# How to use Go Golang to sign a file

Tags: go, openssl, rsa, sign

If I generate my key with openssl like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout testsign.key -out testsign.crt
```

What Go or Golang library or method or tool can I use to sign a file with that key?

Comment: [`rsa.SignPKCS1v15`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#SignPKCS1v15) and [`rsa.SignPSS`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#SignPSS) might be able to help you there.

Comment: Thanks Leon, I will look into those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy the requirements I needed to accomplish with Go & OpenSSL, it's as straight forward as executing command line:

```
    c := "openssl"
    a := []string{"dgst", "-sha512", "-sign", "signature.key", "-out", "FileOut.signed", "FileToBeSigned.txt"}   
    cmd := exec.Command(c, a...)
```